# remote assistance not available on windows 10 home

Tags: desktop, remote, remote-assistance

I am trying to connect from my home PC to my mother-in-laws laptop.

After a few days of trying she saw on her PC that it said remote desktop was not available in her version of windows 10.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Teamviewer is free for personal use

Comment: ^ and far easier to punch through a domestic router/firewall.

Answer (score 3):

Remote Desktop is not available in Windows 10 Home.  However, you dont need it.  Since Windows 7, Windows has had a remote assistance tool built in.  In Windows 10, Quick Assist is built in to all versions.

Have her simply click Start and type Quick Assist and it will show up.  This will allow her to send you a request for help.

Here are some easy to follow [instructions](https://www.technipages.com/windows-send-remote-assistance-invitation) on how to use it in more detail.

While 3rd party programs like TeamViewer and VNC are available, I believe they are overkill for the occasional help session.  They require a non technical user to install software.  They consume resources and there are security risks involved in using them.  Using the built in tool from Microsoft is easy and doesnt require installing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, Remote Desktop is **not available in Windows 10 Home**, you need pro edition to access this feature. All the latest edition of Windows 10 has an **in-built feature** named as **Quick Assist**, if you have an updated version of windows then you can access this feature easily.

Users of Older versions can use remote assistance on windows 10 by first enabling it & then send or receive an invitation.

First, you need to **[Enable Windows Remote assistance on windows 10](https://rktechstudio.com/remote-assistance-on-windows-10/)**, 2 methods to enable it, here's one easy method by which you can do it.

1. Open “Control Panel” and search for ‘remote’. The windows will display all the search results.
2. From the results shown, select the first option “Allow remote access to your computer”. It will directly open the Remote tab in System Properties.
3. Now make sure the “Allow Remote Assistance connections to this computer” checkbox is checked, if not then click on it. Now, Click Advanced option
4. For instance, you can set limits for the use of remote assistance, choose to allow the computer to be used remotely, set the maximum amount of invitations.
5. If you clear the “Allow this computer to be controlled remotely” checkbox, the helpers can see your windows screen, but not take full control of your PC, which is not recommended.
6. After you have configured the settings, click on OK and then Apply the settings by clicking on the apply button and then close all the tabs. That’s it!

After enabling remote assistance on your windows, you can easily **send or receive remote invitations** by which you can allow someone you trust to take access to your pc remotely.

If you want a guide on how to send a remote assistance invitation, then follow this [**step by step guide**](https://rktechstudio.com/how-to-send-remote-assistance-invitation/) which will make things easier to understand.

**Additional Note:** There are some third-party applications and softwares available by which you can do the same, but using Microsoft's inbuilt tool (Remote Assistance/Quick Assist) makes sense and the best part of it - It's completely Free :)